# Disallow user to enter any value apart from 1 to 999 including decimals

Tags: jquery

I want to allow user to enter value from 1 to 999 in the input box

I tried the following

```
<input name="quantity" class="numbers" value=""/>

$('.numbers').keypress(function (e) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val());
    if (value <= 0 || value > 999) {
        return false;
    }
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This does not work, when i enter zero value, i am stuck, here is the link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kcet86s8/4/

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Not jQuery though, can you try with "oninput" in your input field?

Comment: Please give a better explanation than *"does not work"*. You also need to remember you are using the `keypress` event, you can be triggering and getting the old value rather than the updated `0` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this to your question, for clear.

> disallow user to enter any value apart from 1 to 999 including decimals

Your problem is: you want to restrict user input, which depend to the inputed value. But the "keypress" event is fire before the value updated, therefore the value you get is the old value, not the new one(that's easy to check this out)

And the problem in your requirement is you can't get the new value before the input updated, atleast jquery can't do that. So you can't restrict user input at "keypress".

In other way, you can use "keyup". Then revert last value if user input wrong value.
.i.e: https://jsfiddle.net/kcet86s8/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.myval = $('.numbers').val();
    $('.numbers').keyup(function (e) {
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (value <= 0 || value > 999) {
        $(this).val($.myval);
            return false;
        }
        if ((e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57))) {
        $(this).val($.myval);
            return false;
        }
      $.myval = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

User still can sees the input value before it have been reverted. I think it's not perfect but the only way.

---

Update keycode condition to enable numpad input, as @Midas suggested: https://jsfiddle.net/kcet86s8/10/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.myval = $('.numbers').val();
    $('.numbers').keyup(function (e) {
        var value = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (value <= 0 || value > 999) {
        $(this).val($.myval);
            return false;
        }
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && !(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) && !(e.which >= 96 && e.which <= 105)) {
        $(this).val($.myval);
            return false;
        }
      $.myval = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Comment: The example doesn't allow me to type anything at all.

Comment: Checked on FF and Chrome, i can input number from 1~999, like Ibrahim want. But i use "keyup", so if you press multi keys without key up one then $.myval won't be updated, so it's revert to old value (which is blank).

Comment: I found why it doesn't work for me. Your example doesn't seem to support numpad keys, which I was using to type in the box. You should support those as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<input type="number">` element, `input` event `String.prototype.slice()` with parameters `0, -1` to remove last character of `input` value substituting `valueAsNumber` property for `parseInt()` if `false` at first `if` condition

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".numbers").on("input", function(e) {
    var value = this.valueAsNumber;
    if (value <= 0 || value > 999) {
      this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
    }
    // if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    //     return false;
    // }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input name="quantity" type="number" class="numbers" value="" />
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kcet86s8/5/

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Note, if requirement is to also exclude `.` and `-` characters from `input` value you can include `/[^0-9]/.test(value)` at `if` condition `if ((value <= 0 || value > 999) || /[^0-9]/.test(value))` https://jsfiddle.net/kcet86s8/6/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<input type="number">` which has a `min` and `max` attribute:

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="999" value="1">
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)

Comment: I don't want to use this, reason being, it allows you to enter values apart from 1 to 999 and displays the validation error, what i am trying to do is, disallow user to enter any value apart from 1 to 999 including decimals.